# Combating Migration Bloat in Entity Framework Code First Applications

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

Now that some of us have Code First projects that have been running in production for years and have been accumulating lots of Migrations, has anyone run into problems having a large number of them?  Is there such a thing as "too many migrations?"

If so, what is the remedy?  Some caveats:
- Obviously we can't delete & rescaffold the production db.
- We can't delete all migrations, __MigrationHistory, and create a new Initial (in my case) because many of our migrations have data seeds/updates, and even tweaks to the generated commands.

Is there a way/tool to combine migrations into fewer migrations?  Would that even make a difference?

Thanks!

Comment: I have a prod database with code first approach. we have deleted all the migration from migration folder in the project. Where it doesn't run old migration and has the latest one. May be you can try that

Comment: I should add that we use NCrunch to run some automated DB tests, so these tests need all the migrations.

Comment: I would say create a empty migration which contains all your old migrations. Instead of too many migration you will have only one migration. This will reduce the time of migration and increase the speed.

Comment: Would it work like so?  Create an empty migration, do "update-databae" to create the __MigrationHistory record, then put all old migration code into the new one, delete the old ones, delete old __MigrationHistory records, and when pushing to prod, delete all __MigrationHistory records and manually add the new one?

Comment: If all deployed databases are up to date, it is a simple matter to archive the old stuff and establish a new starting point. If you have scattered Seed() code in you Up() methods versus the migration configuration Seed() method that could be an issue.

Comment: [This article](https://cpratt.co/migrating-production-database-with-entity-framework-code-first/) may be of use. It describes a rolling up of several migrations by basically going back to an older model and creating a single replacement.

Comment: @JamesinIndy It should work, because you are rolling up all the migration into single migration and you are deleting _migration table from your database and creating a new one. This table will contain a single migration. 
I would also suggest to get a back up of PROD database before doing these kind of operations to be in safe side.

Comment: @Steve Greene, that actually sounds like a great idea for creating fewer migrations going forward!

Comment: @ISHIDA, I ran into a stumbling block with my tester app.  Everything went smoothly at first (the new combined migration doesn't try to run against the already-established db), until I deleted my db and had it try to scaffold it with the new migration (simulating the NCrunch integration tests).  When the Up method ran, it ran CreateTable("dbo.Accounts"...), then crashed trying to seed that table with data ("Invalid Object Name dbo.Accounts").  I'm guessing I need to trigger a Save between old migration "pieces," but I don't know what context it's using, or if I have access to do that.

Comment: @JamesinIndy I faced this issue too. My first question if you have migration which creates a table why are you trying to run that migration again ? when faced this issue I found there were difference in the schema between PROD db and dev db. I resolved it by deleting that table and let migration create table.

Comment: I would suggest you to rename dbo.Accounts to dbo.Accounts1 and let code migration create a new table and seed it and check both the table for differences and delte the dbo.Accounts1 when you find everything is fine.

Comment: It's only adding the new migration for new scaffoldings, e.g. the NCrunch tests.  The new (combined) migration adds the table and immediately tries to seed it, but it can't because the table doesn't exist (didn't save yet?)

Comment: can you rename existing table and let migration create table and seed it.

Comment: This one is already trying to create it on a new database and seed it.  To clarify, each NCrunch test runs on a completely new instance of the db (creating it and scaffolding it from scratch), so there are no existing tables for it to worry about.

Comment: I found my issue, though.  I was using .NET code to create a new DC to seed my data; if I seed it using SQL statements, I don't have this problem.  I will try to post this solution as an answer today (may not be the only answer, and it doesn't answer the question of whether too many migrations is a problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From ISHIDA's suggestions, I have created an example of one way to combine migrations.  This is by no means the only/correct solution, nor does it answer the question of whether migration bloat is a problem, but it's a darn good start.

To test this, I have a console app with 2 tables, which are:

```
public class Account
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Policy> Policies { get; set; }
}

public class Policy
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int PolicyNumber { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string AccountId { get; set; }
    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
}
```

There are 4 migrations which created these tables, added data, and changed the datatype of PolicyNumber from string to int.  Pretend this program is live and all of these have run in a production environment.

```
public partial class InitialCreate : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Accounts",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 100),
                    AccountNumber = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 10),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropTable("dbo.Accounts");
    }
}

public partial class SeedAccounts : DbMigration
{
    readonly string[] accountIds = new string[] { "IdAcct101", "IdAcct102" };

    public override void Up()
    {
        Sql($"INSERT INTO Accounts (Id, AccountNumber) VALUES ('{accountIds[0]}','101')");
        Sql($"INSERT INTO Accounts (Id, AccountNumber) VALUES ('{accountIds[1]}','102')");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        Sql($"DELETE FROM Accounts WHERE ID = '{accountIds[0]}'");
        Sql($"DELETE FROM Accounts WHERE ID = '{accountIds[1]}'");
    }
}
}

public partial class AddPolicyTable : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Policies",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 100),
                    PolicyNumber = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 100),
                    AccountId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 100),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Accounts", t => t.AccountId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.AccountId);

    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Policies", "AccountId", "dbo.Accounts");
        DropIndex("dbo.Policies", new[] { "AccountId" });
        DropTable("dbo.Policies");
    }
}

public partial class ChangeAndSeedPolicies : DbMigration
{
    readonly string[] accountIds = new string[] { "IdAcct101", "IdAcct102" };
    readonly string[] policyIds = new string[] { "IdPol101a", "IdPol101b", "IdPol102a" };

    public override void Up()
    {
        AlterColumn("dbo.Policies", "PolicyNumber", c => c.Int(nullable: false));

        Sql($"INSERT INTO Policies (Id, AccountId, PolicyNumber) VALUES ('{policyIds[0]}', '{accountIds[0]}', '10101')");
        Sql($"INSERT INTO Policies (Id, AccountId, PolicyNumber) VALUES ('{policyIds[1]}', '{accountIds[0]}', '10102')");
        Sql($"INSERT INTO Policies (Id, AccountId, PolicyNumber) VALUES ('{policyIds[2]}', '{accountIds[1]}', '10201')");

    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        Sql($"DELETE FROM Policies WHERE ID = '{policyIds[0]}'");
        Sql($"DELETE FROM Policies WHERE ID = '{policyIds[1]}'");
        Sql($"DELETE FROM Policies WHERE ID = '{policyIds[2]}'");

        AlterColumn("dbo.Policies", "PolicyNumber", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 100));
    }
}
```

Here is the code in the project's Main:

```
        using (var dc = new DataContext())
        {
            foreach (var account in dc.Accounts.OrderBy(q => q.AccountNumber).ToList())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Account " + account.AccountNumber);

                foreach (var policy in account.Policies)
                    Console.WriteLine("    Policy " + policy.PolicyNumber);
            } 
        }
```

DataContext Class:

```
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext() : base("DefaultConnection") { }

    public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Policy> Policies { get; set; }
}
```

The output is:

```
Account 101
    Policy 10101
    Policy 10102
Account 102
    Policy 10201
```

Very simple.  Now I want to combine these migrations into one.  Remember:

- we don't want to drop & rescaffold because production would have data
  other than what the migrations added
- the prior migrations must be able to be re-run for integration testing & new environments

**These are the steps I followed:**

- back up any environment you'll be running this against.
- create a new migration (it should be blank, as nothing has changed yet)
- in Package Console Manager (PMC), run "update-database" to create the __MigrationHistory record
- Verify the app runs normally at this point
- copy all Up methods from old migrations to the new one
- copy all Down methods from old migrations to the new one **in reverse order**
- Verify the app runs normally at this point (should detect no new migrations needed)
- delete all old migrations
- delete all old __MigrationHistory records (leaving only the new one)
- Verify the app runs normally at this point

To verify the new migration really does everything the old ones did (for new environments or testing), simply delete all tables in the database (including __MigrationHistory), run "update-database" in PMC, and see if it runs.

This is what my new migration looks like:

```
public partial class CombinedMigration : DbMigration
{
    readonly string[] accountIds = new string[] { "IdAcct101", "IdAcct102" };
    readonly string[] policyIds = new string[] { "IdPol101a", "IdPol101b", "IdPol102a" };

    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Accounts",
            c => new
            {
                Id = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 100),
                AccountNumber = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 10),
            })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

        Sql($"INSERT INTO Accounts (Id, AccountNumber) VALUES ('{accountIds[0]}','101')");
        Sql($"INSERT INTO Accounts (Id, AccountNumber) VALUES ('{accountIds[1]}','102')");

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Policies",
            c => new
            {
                Id = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 100),
                PolicyNumber = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 100),
                AccountId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 100),
            })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Accounts", t => t.AccountId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.AccountId);

        AlterColumn("dbo.Policies", "PolicyNumber", c => c.Int(nullable: false));

        Sql($"INSERT INTO Policies (Id, AccountId, PolicyNumber) VALUES ('{policyIds[0]}', '{accountIds[0]}', '10101')");
        Sql($"INSERT INTO Policies (Id, AccountId, PolicyNumber) VALUES ('{policyIds[1]}', '{accountIds[0]}', '10102')");
        Sql($"INSERT INTO Policies (Id, AccountId, PolicyNumber) VALUES ('{policyIds[2]}', '{accountIds[1]}', '10201')");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        // Each prior "Down" section was added in reverse order.

        Sql($"DELETE FROM Policies WHERE ID = '{policyIds[0]}'");
        Sql($"DELETE FROM Policies WHERE ID = '{policyIds[1]}'");
        Sql($"DELETE FROM Policies WHERE ID = '{policyIds[2]}'");

        AlterColumn("dbo.Policies", "PolicyNumber", c => c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 100));

        DropForeignKey("dbo.Policies", "AccountId", "dbo.Accounts");
        DropIndex("dbo.Policies", new[] { "AccountId" });
        DropTable("dbo.Policies");

        Sql($"DELETE FROM Accounts WHERE ID = '{accountIds[0]}'");
        Sql($"DELETE FROM Accounts WHERE ID = '{accountIds[1]}'");

        DropTable("dbo.Accounts");
    }
}
```

Caveat:  If any of your migrations have .NET code that creates a new DC and does some db updates, those may not work when migrations are combined.  For example, if migration 1 adds the Account table, and migration 2 uses .NET code to insert records into Account, it will crash in the combined migration because Account technically hasn't been created yet.  Replacing such statements with Sql('INSERT INTO...") statements will fix this.

Comment: What are you gaining? A smaller number of migration files for 1 giant one with lots of potential for errors. You can always delete migrations at the front if you know all deployed database have had them applied. So if you have 100 migrations, but you know 1 through 50 have been deployed you can delete those. If you are worried about an old database popping up - script it out and stash it before the delete.

Comment: Yes, I am gaining a smaller number of migrations, should the number of migrations ever become an issue.  Also, the post explains why I need all of the original migrations.